# How to insert and get an ArrayList<String> from a mongoDB collection?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

Hi im new to mongodb java driver and need help trying to insert and get an arraylist.

what i want to do is something like this

```
uuid: samplexxxxxxxxx   (this is the index)
user:sam
profiles: [ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4]   <- THIS
...
```

I appreciate suggestions and opinions, if it can be done better too. I am new to both java and mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you using a framework like spring boot data.

Please take a look to this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)